# Associate custom icons to specific extensions on Xubuntu/Xfce

Tags: xubuntu, wine, icons, customization, lutris

First, sorry about my English btw and also sorry if a similar question has been asked before.

Context: I've installed lutris to manage some windows games easily, in this case "osu!".
There isn't a problem when opening the related extensions to the game (.osk, .osr, .osz) since lutris have associated these extensions, but I've noticed that the files related are always displaying the default wine icon.

Is there a way to set custom icons to files related to Wine apps, or to replace the default icon despite through what app will open it? It is just to easily identify them.